# Is it correct to say "I had been working in a bank since I left university until I I got married"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, past-perfect

Say I graduated from university in 2002 and I got married in 2016. And I worked in a bank from 2002 to 2016.

We can use "**from ... to ...**" with the simple past tense, for example, "*I worked in a bank from 2002 to 2016.*"

But I am not sure if we can use past perfect continuous with "**from ... to ...**" to emphasize the continuous progress of the action, for example, "*I had been working in a bank from 2002 until 2016*"

Also, Is it correct to say "*I had been working in a bank since I left university until I I got married*"?

Comment: It sounds a little clunky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are used in relation to a fixed point in time (either now or a specific date).

> When I got married in 2016, I had been working in a bank since leaving university.

Comment: Can I change "when" to "until"? "Until I got married in 2016, I had been working in a bank since leaving university."

Comment: It doesn't feel quite right to use _until_ and _since_ in the same sentence.

Comment: "by the time" or "before" sounds better right. For example, "I had been working in a bank since leaving university by the time I got married"? Does it sound ok?

Comment: Possibly, if you move _By the time I got married_ back to the beginning of the sentence. But it would be much more natural to say something like "After leaving university, I worked in a bank until I got married."